# What does "damned Olympics" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In **[Tears of the Sun](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0314353/)**, *Kelly Lake* say this words to *Lieutenant*.

> Kelly Lake:**These guys run the damned Olympics. They've been closing in
>   on us all night.**
>
> Lieutenant: How long we got?
>
> Kelly Lake: An hour, two tops.

Guys means Referring to Nigerian Soldiers who are pursuing American Soldiers.

What does "damned Olympics" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These guys **run the damned Olympics**. They've been closing in on us all
>   night.

In colloquial English, the emphatic **damned** as it is used there in conjunction with the Olympics has very concentrated meaning.

Consider this analogous example:

> You were arguing with the professor in class today about the role of
>   amino acids in biosynthesis. The guy **wrote the damned textbook** on the subject!

In the *Tears of the Sun* example we can discern the context: the speaker and his group are being chased by some others who are narrowing the gap between them. These others are "closing in" or catching up. They are outrunning the speaker and his group.

The Olympics in your example, and the textbook in the analogous example, serve as  *paradigms* of excellence and achievement. Using the word **damned** as modifier emphasizes that fact, and in emphasizing it, the meaning that results is:

You, with your limited knowledge of biosynthesis, *are nothing* compared to him with his great knowledge of the subject.

We, with our limited running ability, *are nothing* compared to them with their great athletic abilities.

P.S. In the original statement, "to run" means "to control", although there is some wordplay since athletic running is actually involved.  We could change the verb **run** to **own** (They own the Olympics, meaning "they dominate the competition") and the meaning would remain much the same:  they are in charge because they always excel in these competitions.

P.P.S. As to whether it's racist, if the speakers were on cross-country skis and were being chased over the snow by Scandinavians, it would be much the same, IMO.

Comment: Hmmm, while I agree that "to run" could mean "to control" and "to own" at times, I'm not sure if this would apply here. Then again, I haven't actually watched the movie, so who knows, maybe it does mean that, too.

Comment: And interesting rendering of your name :O :D.

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang. Things are a little upside-down at the moment :)  If you don't understand **run** in the slang meaning of "dominate", how do you understand it?

Comment: I had only perceived the character to mean "run" in the literal sense.

Comment: The literal meaning isn't idiomatic, at least to my ear.  We "run the mile" or "run the 100 meter dash" but we don't "run the {competition}" in the sense of "compete at".

Comment: I understand and honestly, I agree with you. I'd normally say, "run in the Olympics." But, hey, who am I to judge? Maybe the actor who had played Kelly Lake had been out of breath and ad-libbed or maybe the writer just felt like saying something like, "[running the Marathon](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/04/22/marathon-men-suicidal-man-will-run-alongside-stranger-talked/)."

Comment: Occam wants to see you in his office, stat.

Comment: Heh, that's the funny thing about his Razor. I would say that I'm the one applying it by not overthinking the sentence and just assuming that the speaker had meant "run" literally.

Comment: There is a possibility the text was written by a non-native-speaker, which would make the question what "run" means moot. But  taking it to mean "competes in" is to underthink it.

Comment: I was with Tᴚoɯɐuo until *to run* means *to control* which it can, and not in that context. I've seen that film at three times and while I never noticed the slip, it is a slip. The meaning is clearly and only *they're at least good enough to run in the (emphasis) Olympics.*

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin: Yes, another plausible explanation is that the word **in** was dropped.  I have never seen the film, and never heard the actor utter those words.  But good idiomatic sense can be made of the statement taking **run** as transitive.

Comment: I'm comfortable with the idiomatic 'run the olympics'. Substituting for e.g 'marathon' or 'quarter-mile' similarly works.  Just think of olympics as 'elite race'.

Comment: However comfortable you are *These guys run the damned Olympics* is not an idiom. It's a mistake.

It's just possible that in a special context, as in a purely technical discussion between expert runners it might be used but don’t you think *just* is the operative word there?

How is *Run the marathon* or *run the 10,000 metres* or *run any specific race you care to mention* really comparable to *take part in a general sports get-together with dozens of disciplines and yes, dozens of races.

Though it’s understandable, one can’t *run the Olympics.*

Comment: Are "damn" and "damned" different?

Comment: @Ives: There's no appreciable difference between **damn** and **damned** *as expletives*.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the phrase...

> These guys run the damned Olympics. They've been closing in on us all night.

means the people chasing the speakers are very fast runners.  People highly qualified, as you would find running in Olympic races.  One grammatically correct version of the first phrase is:

> Those guys run in the damned Olympics....

In spoken English, especially when rushed (as the victims are), it is common to drop connecting words such as prepositions.  Mimicking that behavior in written English forces the reader to rely more on context to understand the phrase, but can it make the dialog seem more natural.

In all, the phrase is a metaphor used to express the speaker's admiration for (positive) or frustration about (negative) the pursuers' abilities.  (In this case it's probably negative, but I'd need to see a larger portion of the text to be sure.)

Americans (and many other English speakers) frequently use the word "damn" to add emphasis to a word or phrase.  "Damn" means "[to curse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damn)" and so "damned" can be interpreted to mean "cursed" or "hated."  However, it's actually rare to hear a speaker use the word in that way today.  Far mor often the word only [adds emphasis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damned) to the speaker's unhappiness or discontent.  When used like this, it's the verbal equivalent of underlining text, bolding text, or ending a sentence with an exclamation point.